# Are C++ class members private by default?

Tags: python, c++

In [Python docs](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/classes.html) it is written that:

> In C++ terminology, normally class members (including the data
>   members) are public (except see below [Private Variables](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/classes.html#tut-private)), and all
>   member functions are virtual.

But we know `C++` class members are private by default.

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: It's explaining Python using C++ terminology. It's saying that in C++ **terminology**, normally all *Python* class members are public.

Comment: so, unlike c++ python's classes have public members?

Comment: Unlike C++, members are public by default and members functions are virtual in Python.

Comment: @LV98 of course :)

Comment: Isn't this actually confusing? I guess they could have simply written as @khelwood said.

Comment: That's what they did. They used C++ *terms* to describe how *Python* classes behave. They didn't say anything about how C++ behaves.

Comment: @LV98 You have to explain this. Because no, that’s not what this means. It’s in fact one of Python’s weaknesses.

Comment: @KonradRudolph it's just a bit of a laugh..

Comment: @LV98 That’s fair.

Comment: @KonradRudolph Weakness?

Comment: @Kratos_bawa Python has no access control (except by convention, via uglified names starting with underscore). This often leads to classes and modules exposing more names than they should, which in turn leads to tight coupling. Ideally APIs are as restricted as possible and cleanly separate between public and private parts.

Comment: @Konrad That's a whole philosophical debate, but underscore naming conventions *are* how you define the public API and the private parts. There's no inherent reason why that's any less useful than `private` keywords. You just seem to not like the syntax ("`_`").

Comment: @deceze The problem isn’t that *I* don’t like the syntax, it’s that clearly lots of people don’t, and therefore routinely forego it, instead just making all/most of their implementation public. As for convention vs. enforcement I’m pretty neutral but a mere underscore is way too innocuous: the *writer* of code will notice that they are intentionally using somebody’s private members, but when *reading* other code the signal gets lost. You actively need to use a linter to find such uses. Other languages have better, more effective conventions.

Comment: @Konrad Not sure I agree with that signal getting lost. The rule is simply to not touch any attributes that start with an underscore when you write code, period. I'm not sure when you might overlook this, as you need to explicitly type that underscore. I look at it the other way around: nothing is particularly keeping you from accessing those attributes, which makes debugging and exploratory programming a lot simpler. In other languages you can also access private members in some way or another, you just have to bend over backwards a bit harder when you want to.

Comment: @deceze “The rule is simply to not touch any attributes that start with an underscore when you write code, period.” — No, that isn’t true at all. If it were we’d have no problem (any underscore in code would be a warning sign) but you *need* to use names starting with underscores *all the time* from your *own* implementation. You’re only not supposed to use the implementation of other modules/classes. Visually these two usages are very similar and sometimes even *indistinguishable* (`foo._bar` might be completely valid if `foo` is of the same type as `self`). That’s precisely the problem.

Comment: @Konrad I see what you're getting at, but frankly that hasn't been an issue in many years of programming Python. ‍♂️ If you're really concerned about that, `__` is your friend. But yes, in modern development, the IDE should help out there as well.

Answer (score 0):

It's explaining Python using C++ terminology. It's saying that in C++ *terminology*, normally all **Python** class members are public, and all member functions are virtual (unlike C++).